# Confused regarding aromaticity

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, aromaticity

[image]
I can understand the aromaticity in the second but can't in the first structure.
The second structure is aromatic since it has a continuous conjugation in the rings, but the first structure has no continuous conjugation, still it's aromatic,  can anyone help me out ? Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I edited the picture. Hope I got 1 and 2 right...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In 1, ring (a) is aromatic, but (b) is not. However the double bond which is in (b) alone will share electrons with ring (a). // In 2, rings (a), (b), and (c) are all aromatic.

Comment: @MaxW I guess I have heard from some source that if one ring is aromatic,then the entire molecule is aromatic. Is that the case?

Comment: @YusufHasan - Well wouldn't the opposite be true too? If some part of the molecule is not aromatic, then the whole molecule is not aromatic? // The point I'm trying to make is that chemistry if often ambiguous. You could say that "Looking at the NMR for  compound 1, it is aromatic." What is meant is that it has an *aromatic group,* not that all carbon-carbon bonds in the compound are aromatic.

Comment: @MaxW Ok, I see..No, the thing I had in mind was that, maybe if you have atleast one aromatic ring and all other non-aromatic or aromatic ones, then you can call the entire molecule aromatic. But,if the molecule has even one anti-aromatic ring, then we can't term the entire thing aromatic. Does this make any sense?

Comment: @YusufHasan - Sorry I made my point poorly. Let me try again. // When we say that a compound is *aliphatic* then it has no aromatic bonding. // When we say that a compound is *aromatic*, then there is some aromatic bonding. But this is ambiguous. It isn't clear if all the C-C bonds are aromatic, or just if some of them are.

Comment: Compound 2 is a [polycyclic aromatic hydrocarbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycyclic_aromatic_hydrocarbon) named phenanthrene.

Comment: Dear OP, I have tried to fix your question best as I could, but you *really* need to work on your English grammar. And vocabulary.

Comment: I still didn't get the answer despite going on the similar question asked previously, the thing is it neither have 4n+2π e and also i can't see a continuous conjugation ,sorry ,but I'm the basic level student still learning to grasp organic chemistry ! What yusuf had said is if one of the ring  is aromatic whole structure would posses some sort of aromatic character ,is it true? If so then MaxW also got a good point. What reason(s) should i state the  for this compound to be aromatic?

Answer (score 0):

"Aromatic" is a qualitative term. "Aromatic" is also ambiguous. Mitheron's reference to the question about "Is 1,2-dihydronaphthalene aromatic?" lists some of the rules that are applied, but the final judge is your teacher: what would the teacher say?

Long ago, my professor said that aromaticity was the measure of surprise that an experimenter had when he determined the heat of combustion of a compound and found that it was considerably less than he expected from his calculations. He would attribute this deficiency to aromaticity. The units of "surprise" have not been established, and have not been established for aromaticity, either.

Comment: Okay so I'll consider this as a very rare exception of compound showing aromaticity, well do you know any other such organic compounds having this strange behavior, it will surely come in handy in future.

Comment: I've also heard of Friends saying if any of the ring posses a aromatic nature there's some sort of aromaticity developed in whole structure ! Is it? Wouldn't then opposite be true?

Comment: Well, the whole point of "aromaticity" is that the system is considerably more stable than the sum of the individual parts, and in addition, contains a ring, like the first-known aromatic compounds, such as toluene and xylene. It's a discussion topic: there is a ring, some kind of symmetry, a neat molecular orbital system, with lower bonding and higher anti-bonding orbitals, all kinds of minutiae that good chemists like to bond over (or anti-bond over). And rules to discuss.